# Group_by then filter with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

First of all, please let me know if what I'm doing is poor use of dplyr because I'm not sure if I'm approaching this in the best way. I have the following dataframe:

```
mydf = data.frame(user = c(7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8),
                  col1 = c('0','0','1','1','0','3','NULL','3','3','0','1','0','0'),
                  col2 = runif(n=13),
                  col3 = letters[1:13], 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> mydf
   user col1      col2 col3
1     7    0 0.7607907    a
2     7    0 0.1580448    b
3     7    1 0.8063540    c
4     7    1 0.7331512    d
5     7    0 0.2433631    e
6     7    3 0.2357065    f
7     7 NULL 0.4864172    g
8     8    3 0.6806089    h
9     8    3 0.2229874    i
10    8    0 0.6187911    j
11    8    1 0.7617177    k
12    8    0 0.5884821    l
13    8    0 0.4985750    m
```

The filtering I would like to do is a bit wordy, but I'll try - I would like to filter the dataframe by removing all rows where **col1 == '0'** if that row occurs AFTER the first row for that user where **col1 == '1'**. (bolded indicates i messed up the original question, and switched the 0 and 1).

For example, for user 7,  the 3rd row has col1 == '1', so I'd like to filter all rows after row 3 where col1 == '0' (in this case, only row 5). Then, for user 8, the 11th row is the first row for this user where col1 == '1', so I'd then like to filter rows 12 and 13, since col1 == '0'.

My final output should be something like this:

```
> mydf
   user col1      col2 col3
1     7    0 0.7607907    a
2     7    0 0.1580448    b
3     7    1 0.8063540    c
4     7    1 0.7331512    d
6     7    3 0.2357065    f
7     7 NULL 0.4864172    g
8     8    3 0.6806089    h
9     8    3 0.2229874    i
10    8    0 0.6187911    j
11    8    1 0.7617177    k
```

I've tried the following, but it didn't work. I thought adding a rownums column, then grouping by user, and then filtering how I've described would work. My thoughts are that there is something wrong with my filter call:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(rownums = 1:nrow(mydf)) %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(!(col1 == "0" & rownums > min(which(col1 == "1"))))

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   col0 [2]
   user  col1      col2  col3 rownums
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1     7     0 0.2088034     a       1
2     7     0 0.2081894     b       2
3     7     1 0.1825428     c       3
4     7     1 0.2143353     d       4
5     7     3 0.1979774     f       6
6     7  NULL 0.2990799     g       7
7     8     3 0.7808038     h       8
8     8     3 0.1694272     i       9
9     8     1 0.1526450     k      11
```

The difference between this output, and the correct output, is that this output incorrectly also filtered row 10 of the original dataframe.

Any help with this is appreciated!

EDIT - I'm particularly curious if group_by() %>% filter() is bad practice in R with regards to dplyr. 99% of my group_by() are followed by summarize(), which obviously makes more sense.

EDIT2 - I think I've got it!

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(col0) %>%
  mutate(rownums = 1:length(col0)) %>%
  filter(!(col1 == "0" & rownums > min(which(col1 == "1"))))
```

Simply flipping the order of the mutate() and group_by() calls, and tweaking the mutate() call a bit, looks to have gotten it done. I'm open to hearing a better approach though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `cumany` function, which is useful for these sequential conditions, like this:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(seen_one = cumany(col1 == "1")) %>%
  filter(!seen_one | col1 != "0")
```

That is mark all rows after `"1"` has been in the 'stream' with `seen_one`, and then keep the rows where one of the conditions is not met. (Semantics of `filter` require to invert the condition to 'get rid' of the rows, `!(A & B) == !A | !B`.)

Comment: brilliant idea imo, though the output significantly differs from what OP expects

Comment: The OP is not very consistent with the requirements, first he says remove rows where col1 == 1, and then removes rows 12 and 13, where the col1 == 0.

Comment: like i said the filtering was wordy, and at second glance i messed it up

Comment: Okay, so does my code do what you intend to? If not, please fix your 'wordy' description.

Comment: its been fixed, and no my desired output is still what's posted.

Comment: not great on my part having a typo in an already wordy question, sorry about that, thanks for the time in answering.

Comment: ive edited your solution with the correct one, using cumany, its waiting for review to update, but i think this is the best answer - like the use of cumany here

Answer (score 2):

Could be solved by updating your attempt a little :

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
   group_by(user) %>%
   filter(col1 != 0 | row_number() < which.max(col1 == 1))


#    user   col1        col2  col3
#   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>
# 1     7     0 0.756522673     a
# 2     7     0 0.168314555     b
# 3     7     1 0.977254798     c
# 4     7     1 0.722721694     d
# 5     7     3 0.407849378     f
# 6     7  NULL 0.245335151     g
# 7     8     3 0.003423735     h
# 8     8     3 0.191716738     i
# 9     8     0 0.626846893     j
#10     8     1 0.546459621     k
```

Using `filter` we select all the rows where `col1` is not equal to 0 or those rows where the current row is less than the index of first occurrence of 1 for that group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(user) %>% 
 mutate(id1 = row_number(), new_col = max(which(col1 == 1)+1)) %>% 
 filter(!(col1 == 0 & id1 >= new_col))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 6
> # Groups:   user [2]
>     user  col1       col2  col3   id1 new_col
>    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
>  1     7     0 0.54742608     a     1       5
>  2     7     0 0.89271859     b     2       5
>  3     7     1 0.48999057     c     3       5
>  4     7     1 0.17163211     d     4       5
>  5     7     3 0.96146770     f     6       5
>  6     7  NULL 0.31368382     g     7       5
>  7     8     3 0.82051455     h     1       5
>  8     8     3 0.30705440     i     2       5
>  9     8     0 0.18545358     j     3       5
> 10     8     1 0.04834678     k     4       5
> ```

Comment: I like the idea of creating the additional columns in mutate(), rather than having an overly complex filter(). the mutate() %>% filter() makes the filter easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

alternately, building on the direction @liborm's answer provides:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  mutate(k = cumany(col1 == '0'), j = cumany(col1 == '1')) %>%
  filter(!(col1 == 0 & k == TRUE & j == TRUE)) %>%
  select(-k,-j)
```

returns:

```
    user  col1  col2  col3
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
 1     7     0     1     a
 2     7     0     1     b
 3     7     1     0     c
 4     7     1     0     d
 5     7     3     0     f
 6     7  NULL     1     g
 7     8     3     0     h
 8     8     3     1     i
 9     8     0     1     j
10     8     1     0     k
```